# Close WordPress accordion when returning to page

Tags: wordpress, accordion

I'm using an accordion section on my WordPress website with the default state being closed. Inside the accordion are three clickable posts that are set up as biographies. When I click on a post inside the accordion, it takes me to the post's page, but when I click to go back in my browser to the previous page with the accordion, the accordion begins in a closed state and then opens back up on its own, making things a bit jumpy. Also, when I go back to the page, the URL shows the accordion section's ID so the URL becomes /#1620851330855-0d9c4657-80a6. I'm looking for a solution that will keep the accordions default closed state once going back to the page. I also deactivated the caching plugin thinking that would help, but no success.

The page in question is https://shodair.org/hope-takes-flight and the accordion is in the Committees section with the heading Honorary Campaign Chairs. I have not added any custom script or CSS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add this code in your js file      
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var delay = 100; setTimeout(function() { 
            $('.elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active');
            $('.elementor-tab-content').css('display', 'none'); }, delay); 
            });
```